# Let $(Y_n)_{n \ge 1}$ be the number of fair coin tosses until 'heads' appears $n$ times. Is $(Y_n)_{n \ge 1}$ a (stationary) Markov chain?

Tags: probability, markov-chains, markov-process

> Let $X$ be the random variable counting the number of fair coin tosses until 'heads' appears for the first time. Let $(Y_n)_{n \ge 1}$ be the number of fair coin tosses until 'heads' appears $n$ times. Hence, $Y_{n+1}= Y_n + X_{n+1}$, where  $(X_n)_{n \ge 1}$ are i.i.d random variables of the same distribution of $X$.
>
> (a) Is $(Y_n)_{n \ge 1}$ a Markov chain?
>
> (b) Is $(Y_n)_{n \ge 1}$ stationary?

My thoughts so far:

(a) 
Since $Y_{n+1}$ directly depends on $Y_n$, I assume the process to be indeed a Markov chain. I also tried to find a transition matrix $P$ but I don't know if it's correct:

$$P = \begin{pmatrix} 
      \frac{1}{2} & \frac{1}{2} & 0& \cdots & 0 \\
      0 & \frac{1}{2} & \frac{1}{2} & \cdots & 0 \\
      \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
      0 & 0 & 0 & \frac{1}{2} & \frac{1}{2} \\
      0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1
      \end{pmatrix}$$
So the idea is that one either stays in the current state or advances if another 'heads' comes up until one has $n$ heads.

(b)
 Unfortunately I can't really answer this question as I've not grasped the concept of stationarity yet. I already know how to calculate the stationary distribution given a specific transition matrix but not how to argue whether it actually exists. Also, I didn't come to a proper result when I tried to calculate the stationary distribution of the matrix above, so I assume it either doesn't exist, the matrix is incorrect or I made a mistake.

Comment: A Markov chain is stationary iff its initial distribution is a stationary distribution. Since $Y_n$ is absorbing, what can you say about its stationary distribution(s)?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think your transition matrix is correct. Re-think what values $Y_n$ can take and what the states of your purported Markov chain would be.

You can directly check the Markov property by computing
$$P(Y_{n+1} = y_{n+1} \mid Y_n = y_n, Y_{n-1} = y_{n-1}, \ldots, Y_1=y_1)$$
and checking whether it only depends on $y_n$ and $y_{n+1}$.

Try to just write down the [definition of stationarity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stationary_process#Definition) and see whether it holds. If you want to start with a sanity check, ask yourself if you think the distribution of $Y_{10}$ is the same as the distribution of $Y_{100}$.

Comment: Sorry but I still have issues getting it right. Isn't it so that the row $i$ of the Markov chain represents the number of heads up to the current toss and the column $j$ represents the number of heads after the toss? That's why I initially thought that the probability of either staying at or advancing from the current state (= number of heads) would be $\frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: @Mathician Revisit the definition of $Y_n$: it is the number of tosses until the $n$th head. The states of the Markov chain are positive integers, and a transition from, say, state $5$ to state $8$ would correspond to getting the $n$th head on the $5$th toss and then getting the $(n+1)$st head on the $8$th toss (for some $n$).